# Can I pray for a non muslim relative?

Tags: salat, family

I’m a born muslim, both my parents are muslims but my mom is european so she was born a christian and my family from her side are all christians. My grandmother from my moms side passed away and I really cared about her. She was a christian. is it prohibited or would it be okay for me to pray for Allah to forgive her and send her to Jannah?

Answer (score 2):

It is a point of agreement among the scholars that asking forgiveness for a person who has died as a disbeliever is unlawful and forbidden.

Allah says in the Quran:

> It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire. (9:113)

And Allah says:

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin. (4:48)

See here for some more detail: http://seekersguidance.org/ans-blog/2011/05/23/can-we-pray-for-non-muslims-who-passed-away/

Comment: is it a sin if I have already prayed for her? I was unaware of this and I just came to know its forbidden

Comment: @user02 Mistakes are not sinful. You should avoid doing it in the future In sha Allah.